# convert neo4j value to neo4j node

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

```
I want to convert neo4j value to neo4j node and this is what I'm doing,

  StatementResult result1 = session.run("MATCH (n) where n.label = {label}   RETURN ID(n) ",parameters( "label", "C0000119") );
     Node src= null;
    while ( result1.hasNext() )
    {
        Record record1 = result1.next();
        System.out.println( record1.get(0) );
        //Node src  getNodebyID 
        src = (Node) record1.get(record1.get(0).toString());
    }
```

I'm unable to get a node, is there some method to get a node in JAVA that being returned by Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially querying `MATCH (n) where n.label = "C0000119" RETURN ID(n)`, which looks for nodes with the **property** named label with a value of *C0000119*.

What you want to do is `MATCH (n:C0000119) RETURN ID(n)` or `MATCH (n) WHERE n:C0000119 RETURN ID(n)` to get the id of the node (or multiple nodes) with the label C0000119.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the nodes you want actually have a `label` *property* (as opposed to a node [label](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-labels)), the following code snippet should result in a `nodes` list containing all the matching nodes:

```
StatementResult result1 = session.run(
    "MATCH (n) where n.label = {label} RETURN n",
    parameters( "label", "C0000119")
);
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
while ( result1.hasNext() )
{
    Record record = result1.next();
    Value value = record.get("n");
    System.out.println( value.asString() );
    nodes.add(value.asNode());
}
```